# Website won't scroll and footer stuck in header

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, header, footer

After the last Wordpress update, the header/footer and scrolling functionality became affected but only on certain devices. When it's not displaying properly, the footer's copyright statement appears in the header, and you are unable to scroll down each of the webpages.

I tried changing the overflow to scroll (it was hidden) but it did not correct the issues. Any idea where things went awry after the Wordpress update? I've scoured through everything and don't know what I am missing.

www.cicada.marketing is the website experiencing the problems.

Comment: affected but only on certain devices. What kind of device ?

Comment: Check that your body and html height is set to 100%

Comment: Hm, is `<style scoped>` supported by many browsers yet?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier - I can't get it to work on iphone 6, we tested on Androids and it worked on one but not another, we tested on Macs and it worked on a few but not one other, and we can't get it to work on iPads.

Comment: @RiaanV - It's set to 100%.

Comment: `}
html {
 font-smooth: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body { 
 margin: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: #555;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;`

Comment: Add position absolute and then bottom: 0px;